# How can I block doubleclick.net cookie from my wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, cookies, cookieconsent

I have tested my wordpress website on Cookiemetrix.com and it reported me that my page is not comply with EU Cookie Law. [Cookie scan report](https://www.cookiemetrix.com/display-report/colorpointadvertising.ro/8010c1896cd8945ad07fc25adfbad120) because it found a doubleclick.net cookie named IDE. Could this cookie come from an installed plugin? What is the solution to get this website to pass the cookiemtrix test?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is likely a Google Advertising cookie. Excerpt below from [their documentation.](https://policies.google.com/technologies/types?hl=en)

Could it come from a plugin? Sure.

You could turn off all the plugins empty your cookies and activate them one by one  to see when the cookie appears. but hopefully seeing that the cookie is from Google helps narrow things.

> We also use one or more cookies for advertising we serve across the
>   web. One of the main advertising cookies on non-Google sites is named
>   ‘IDE‘ and is stored in browsers under the domain doubleclick.net.
>   Another is stored in google.com and is called ANID. We use other
>   cookies with names such as DSID, FLC, AID, TAID, and exchange_uid.
>   Other Google properties, like YouTube, may also use these cookies to
>   show you more relevant ads.

Comment: The problem is that I cant see the 'IDE' cookie in my browser, so I dont know how to debug.